# Magento 2.3 getResource is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: category-listing, magento2.3.4, deprecated

I have a product attribute label get in category page below way.

```
<?php 
$tablecolor = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('xyz'); // attribute name
$attrTestValue = $tablecolor->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $Label = $_product->getAttributeLabel('xyz');
?>
```

*it is working fine* 

but it is depricated in magento 2.3 
**What is a suggested an alternative way to get labels without using deprecated method?**

Answer (score 0):

you can just inject an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` in your class and use that one instead of `$product->getResource()`;

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
 */
private $productResource;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->productResource = $productResource;
    ....
}
```

And use this inside your methods

```
$tablecolor = $productResource->getAttribute('xyz');
```

This is how you can use the product resource model, but in your specific case, when you want to get an instance of a certain attribute you can use the product attribute repository

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
 */
private $attributeRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    ....
}
```

and later use this

```
try {
    $tablecolor = $attributeRepository->get('xyz'); 
    //do soemthing with tablecolor
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    //the attribute does not exist
}
```

If you want to only get the label of an option of a dropdown attribute for a specific product you can just use this

```
$product->getAttributeText('xyz');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i want to get attribute label how can achieve that?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It now contains a way to use the product resource model, a way to get an instance of a product attribute and how to get the attribute option label for a specific product. I hope I covered all your needs.

Comment: yes right but i want to implement in category page so how can do this ? i have no more experience with this so and custom extension create? or xyz and i am using magento 2.3.4